How to define Dag dependency
I have a requirement where I have 3 DAGS(DAG A , DAG B, DAG C)  for three different instances which are scheduled at morning 9 AM everyday.. Each DAG loads data to staging tables in BigQuery and after that a SP is created in curated layer which basically does the Union all of the tables from these 3 instances.
The requirement is the curated SP will be triggered only when these 3 dags have completed loading data to the staging tables. I cannot use Sensors because of higher costing issues and this requirement is to be fulfilled only using Airflow.
+-------------------+         +-------------------+
|       DAG A       | ----> | Success           | (if data loaded)
+-------------------+         +-------------------+
                             |
                             v
+-------------------+         +-------------------+
|       DAG B       | ----> | Success           | (if data loaded)
+-------------------+         +-------------------+
                             |
                             v
+-------------------+         +-------------------+
|       DAG C       | ----> | Success           | (if data loaded)
+-------------------+         +-------------------+
                             | (All DAGs must succeed)
                             v
+--------------------------+
|  curated_sp_dag (all_success)| (Triggered only when all upstream succeed)
+--------------------------+
                             |
                             v
+-------------------+
| BigQueryOperator  | (Execute SP)
+-------------------+

Any leads will be very helpful.

Sensors are the natural way to do this. You should use them. They are cheap and easy. There is no reason not to use them. You can also regroup all your tasks in a unique DAG.

as per client's requirement they do not want to use sensors.

Then your only solution is to create a Unique DAG that handles dependencies. IMO you should try to change your client's requirement, Airflow without sensors makes no sense.
